# What to do if 2 classes have the same package statement

Tags: java

I'm running into a problem where 2 classes from 2 different packages (owned by the same group) have the same name and package statement

**Package 1**

```
package com.placeholder.constants.Constants

public class Constants{}
```

**Package 2**

```
package com.placeholder.constants.Constants

public class Constants{}
```

If I'm working on Package 1 but want to reference this Constants class in Package 2, is this even possible?

Comment: Change one of them.

Comment: By the way, `example` is a domain name [officially reserved](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606) for such demonstration purposes. So, `com.example.constants`.

Comment: Using multiple classloaders it might be possible but I'd doubt this is worth the hassle. Why do you have that structure in the first place? Als, why do you have a package named `...Constants` that also contains a class named `Constants`? Is that typo? - Also: "from 2 different packages" - they're actually using the _same_ (split) package but probably are located in multiple projects, right?

Comment: @Thomas Not just that: a package named constants, containing a package named Constants, containing a class named Constants. Do you think these values change or are they constant?

Answer (score 3):

## Cannot duplicate class name within same package

> where 2 classes from 2 different package

But they are *not* two different packages. You’ve used the same package name for both.

> want to reference this Constants class in Package 2

Use either:

- A different package name
- A different name for your new class

You cannot define two classes with the same name in the same package, for obvious reasons.

The purpose of packages in Java is to create a [namespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace). Your duplicate class name violates that namespace.

## Design problems

> `package com.placeholder.constants.Constants`

That is not a proper package name. You’ve mixed the class name into the package name. The package should be `package com.placeholder.constants`.

This cross-naming problem of yours raises the possibility that you have a less than optimal class design. You might want to pause a moment to look at the bigger picture.

And if you have that many constants to name, I wonder if some of those should really be `enum` types. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html). Tip: In Java 16 and later, enums can be defined locally, within an a method — a new alternative to being defined as a nested class or defined as a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a name conflict. If possible, try to enter the full name of the package.class_location

Comment: The package declaration of both classes is the same as well. So using the full name doesn't help here.